# Getting download url of multiple files inside Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an Android App where Firebase is the backed. In my app, I have some selected images that I have stored inside my Firebase storage by direct uploading (Without coding).

Now I have to view that images in my app through a recycle view. For that purpose, I have to get the download URL of all the images and put them into my Firebase real-time database programmatically so that I can access the URL to my app. Is there any methods available for that?

I have tried to iterate through storage, unfortunately there is no method for that.

Comment: store the URL's inside the realtime database and then iterate over them.

Comment: i know that..but.. i am having thousands of images. then how can i?

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no way to iterate a list of files in Firebase Storage using the Firebase SDKs.  Instead, after you upload a file, you should *also* store its download URL in Firebase Realtime Database (or some other place) that you can query for the download URLs.

Comment: Ok I knows that. What if i told you that i have 1000+ files to upload and to get the download link. So this way of approach makes wasting the time.

Comment: It sounds like you have some post-processing to do with `gsutil` and a script or program you write to backfill the download urls for all these uploaded files. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a proper answer to this question for 2 days. What i found is, There is no proper API or Class in Firebase Storage for the same purpose. If you guys want to do the same effectively, get the files in your code programmatically and upload them to firebase storage through a loop. Through that you can get the download links after uploading of each files. Store it in the Real time Database of Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that can can return a file. You can set up a /link url in the hosting to that function.